# same webview in two activity for session in php - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-webview

I using `Webview` in my application - when running application i want show `singup_activity.xml` and content `webview1`. when user click login button i want show `home_activity.xml` and content it same `webview1` (same `webview` in `singup_activity.xml` - this for session in php)

Comment: Do you want to create a Login/Register application ???

Comment: @KamelJahloug yes but with webview and have two activity . first for singUp and second for home

Comment: See this very interesting example https://github.com/tonikami/NEWLoginRegister it make a simple Login/Register App it provide a `Login.php` and `Register.php` to allow you add an account throw this app Hope that help.

Comment: I think that this tutorial is available on `Youtube` you can even watch how he did it.

Comment: @KamelJahloug ok I well try it then tell you what happen .. giv me url youtube if found

Comment: but i want it in webview  he dont use webview @KamelJahloug :(

Comment: It's true, i am sorry i just see the word WebView